# Designing stack and queue from scratch in C

Tags: beginner, c, reinventing-the-wheel, stack, queue

As a beginner and curious guy I'm interested in implementing data structures and algorithms from scratch. Here's my implementation of *Stack* and *Queue*, the most fundamental data structures.

Are there are any mistakes/ memory leaks in the code that I have missed? How I can improve my implementation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct NODE {
    int data;
    struct NODE *next_node;

    } NODE;


NODE *check_queue(NODE *head);
NODE *check_stack(NODE *head);
void push_node(NODE **head, int value);
void enqueue_node(NODE **head, int value, NODE **tail);
int  pop(NODE **s_head);
int  dequeue(NODE **q_head);
void print_stack(NODE *head);
void print_queue(NODE *head);
void free_memory(NODE **head);



int main(){

    NODE *Q_head = NULL;
    NODE *Q_tail = NULL;
    NODE *S_head = NULL;
    /*operations here*/

    return 0;
}

/*----- check functions for queue and stack if empty-----------*/    

NODE *check_queue(NODE *head){
    return head;
}


NODE *check_stack(NODE *head){
    return head;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/



void push_node(NODE **head, int value){

    NODE *cache;
    cache = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    cache->data = value;
    /*first commit / allocate a new head*/

    if ((*head) == NULL) {
        cache->next_node = NULL;
        (*head) = cache; /*assign the cache to head head*/
    }

    else {
        /*point to the previous head*/
        cache->next_node = (*head);
        (*head) = cache;
    }
}


void enqueue_node(NODE **head, int value, NODE **tail) {

    NODE *cache;
    cache = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    cache->data = value;
    cache->next_node = NULL;

    if ((*head) == NULL && (*tail) == NULL) {
        (*head) = cache; /*assign the cache to head*/
        /*now assign tail the job as a cachet head and extends the queue*/
        (*tail) = (*head);
    }

    else {
        /*now tail is the representative of head and extened the queue*/
        (*tail)->next_node = cache;
        (*tail) = cache;
    }
}


int pop(NODE **s_head){

    if(check_stack((*s_head)) == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty ! ! !\n");
        return -1;
    }

    else {
        /*put next head into a cache, free present head, take next head to present head*/
        NODE *cache ;
        cache = (*s_head)->next_node;
        int popped_value = (*s_head)->data;
        free((*s_head));
        (*s_head) = cache;
        return popped_value;
    }
}



int dequeue(NODE **q_head){

    if(check_queue((*q_head)) == NULL){
        printf("queue is empty ! ! !\n");
        return -1;
    }

    else {
        /*ditto of stack as we've got queue sequence*/

        NODE *cache ;
        cache = (*q_head)->next_node;
        int dequeued_value = (*q_head)->data;
        free((*q_head));
        (*q_head) = cache;
        return dequeued_value;
    }
}





void print_stack(NODE *head){

    while (head) {

        printf(" %d \n", head->data);
        printf(" |\n");
        head = head->next_node;
    }

    /*for further assurance*/
    if ( head == NULL){
        printf("NULL\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}






void print_queue(NODE *q_head){

    while (q_head) {


        // printf(" %d  -> ", head->next_node);
        printf(" %d  -> ", q_head->data);
        q_head = q_head->next_node;
    }
    /*for further assurance*/
    if ( q_head == NULL){
            printf("NULL\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}


void free_memory(NODE **head){
    NODE *cache_head;

    while ((*head)) {

        /*assign next head to the cache*/
        cache_head = (*head)->next_node;
        free((*head));
        (*head) = cache_head;
    }

    printf("memory release complete !!! \n");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**casting and malloc**

Unnecessary casting is generally frowned upon.  `malloc` returns a `void*`, so you don't need to cast it when you're assigned it.

```
cache = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

can just be

```
cache = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

**Bug**

You've got a bug in your dequeue function.  It doesn't update tail, which means that if you empty the queue, then start adding to it again you get errors.

```
enqueue_node(&Q_head, 1, &Q_tail);
printf("%d\n", dequeue(&Q_head));
enqueue_node(&Q_head, 1, &Q_tail);
printf("%d\n", dequeue(&Q_head));
```

Results in:

> ```
> 1
> queue is empty ! ! !
> -1
> ```

**naming**

It's a little odd that your push/enqueue methods have have a `_node` postfix, but your pop/dequeue methods don't.  I'd pick one and stick to it.

**heads and tails**

I'd rather see the head and tail of the queue wrapped up together in a queue structure.  This means that you only have to pass one parameter (the queue) into your enqueue/dequeue.  It also means that if you decide to change the way you implement the queue, your clients aren't impacted.

**Are Queues Stacks?**

As you've implemented it, it's possible to call stack functions on queue nodes and queue functions on stack nodes.  Is this really desirable?  If not, then making the change above to introduce a `QUEUE` structure that wraps a `QNODE` head and `QNODE` tail would mean that you would at least have some level of type safety and the compiler would warn you if you tried to call dequeue on your stack.

Comment: I've just simply edited `if ((*head) == NULL && (*tail) == NULL){...}` to `if ((*head) == NULL){...}` that would enable the snippet update new tail in `enqueue()` function. May I wish an elaborated discussion on **bug** and  **heads and tails** section please.

Comment: what I've noticed a queue and stack are same however they differ in en-queuing and pushing order. Other than can't they be printed and popped/de-queued in same order ? _first man in the queue is head and last book in a stack is the head, isn't it? _ however, if I'm wrong please give me some elaborated discussion.

Comment: @ph03n1x try `push_node(&Q_head, 3);enqueue_node(&Q_head, 1, &Q_tail)` with your current fix.

Comment: @ph03n1x The structure of a stack and queue is very similar and it's not uncommon for collections to support 'add_end', 'add_front' type functions however, whilst I might model a linked_list that supported these methods I wouldn't expose them that way for my stack and queue.  When I make the decision to use a queue, it's usually because I want something optimized for a FIFO approach, rather than something that is flexible.  However, opinions can obviously differ.

Comment: Well, in that case we can declare stack head and queue head/tail in global territory that our user can only give the values and rest of the works will be done in `push_node(int value);` and `enqueue_node(int value);` functions.  Anyway, where can I see the Queue template source/ _implementation_ code of C++ STL ? Please give me a link of source.

Answer (score 2):

@forsvarir covered most of the important points already, but I have this additional comment:

#### Useless functions

I found these functions to be useless:

> ```
> NODE *check_queue(NODE *head){
>     return head;
> }
>
> NODE *check_stack(NODE *head){
>     return head;
> }
> ```

All these functions do is return the argument passed in.  I can sort of see what you were trying to do, though.  You were probably trying to write functions to check if the queue/stack are empty.  But those functions should return `bool`s, not pointers:

```
bool is_stack_empty(const NODE *head)
{
    return head == NULL;
}
bool is_queue_empty(const QUEUE *q)
{
    return q->head == NULL;
}
```